# ms17-010 is not showing in WSUS (WannaCry Ransomware)

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, wsus

I am trying to push update MS17-010 in my environment but unfortunatly it is not showing in WSUS.

I am targeting it for Win 7 devices.

Win 7 is selected in product category but this update is not showing.

Please advise what kind of category needs to selected or any alternate method to deploy this update from WSUS.

Here is the microsoft link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4013389/title

I think it would be wise to create a powershell script to check the status on machine. At least we would have report or i can say confirmation.

Comment: It's in the monthly and security rollups.See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4012212

Comment: are you sure those are in security rollups for Win 7/10?

Comment: So, i just need to deploy the security rollsups for March 2017?

Comment: The rollups include MS17-010 Security update for Windows SMB Server according to the link in my last comment.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/MS17-010 Has a list of all the patches for literally every version of Windows, even XP, if you understand it's KB is the same as Vista KB.

Comment: https://arstechnica.com/security/2017/05/wcry-is-so-mean-microsoft-issues-patch-for-3-unsupported-windows-versions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the MS bulletin page for MS17-010:

> https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms17-010.aspx

Which does indeed point you to KB4013380:

> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4013389/title

However, that article in turn lists several other KB articles covering various  products effected or patches addressing this vulnerability:

> - [4012598](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/4012598) MS17-010: Description of the security update for Windows SMB Server: March 14, 2017
> - [4012216](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/4012216) March 2017 Security Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2
> - [4012213](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/4012213) March 2017 Security Only Quality Update for Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2
> - [4012217](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/4012217) March 2017 Security Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows Server 2012
> - [4012214](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/4012214) March 2017 Security Only Quality Update for Windows Server 2012
> - [4012215](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/4012215) March 2017 Security Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows 7 SP1 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1
> - [4012212](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/4012212) March 2017 Security Only Quality Update for Windows 7 SP1 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1
> - [4013429](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/4013429) March 13, 2017—KB4013429 (OS Build 933)
> - [4012606](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/4012606) March 14, 2017—KB4012606 (OS Build 17312)
> - [4013198](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/4013198) March 14, 2017—KB4013198 (OS Build 830)

Any one or several of those may show up for you in WSUS, depending on which products are found in your environment.

In my own systems, that means I need to check for both 4012215 and 4012212. However, I don't have to manage any Windows 8 or Server 2012 machines. If those operating systems matter to you, the list is a bit longer.

Additionally, the monthly quality rollups really are rollups. I have machines that failed the March update, but succeeded in April or May. These machines still show "Failed" when I look at the WSUS reports for these KB#'s, but they're okay because they have the later updates.

Answer (score 3):

It's MS17-006 / KB 4012215 (4012212) for Windows 7 / 2k8